# TReading Residual Plot: Omitted Variable Bias of Dummy Variable

Tags: least-squares, scatterplot, residuals

I have a plot of the residuals versus fitted values of an OLS model such that the shape of the plot are two identical randomly scattered clouds, one above and one below the $\hat{e} = 0$ line. Can I say that the model is suffering from omitted variable bias, particularly that the model is missing a dummy variable? If I was able to find said variable (and correctly measure it), and include it in the model, could this correct the plot so that there is a single cloud scattered in the residual plot? The plot is below:

[image]

Comment: No you cannot - in any way - test for omitted variable bias since you have nothing to benchmark against. It does however sound like you a (non)-constant variance problem - which is easy to fix

Comment: So, I know that my residuals have a bivariate normal distribution, which I think is causing the issue. Is there anyway to correct for that?

Comment: Can you update with a description of the data, the estimates and the plot.

Comment: Updated with the plot @Repmat

Comment: Following @Repmat's comment we still want to know more about the data. The simplest situation in which I expect to see similar patterns is a linear probability model with a binary response and mean about 0.5 and enormous scatter so that most residuals are about 0.5 or -0.5. Tell us that isn't so....